# how to convert in python negative value objects in dataframe to float

Tags: python, pandas, string, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to create function a which converts objects to float. Tried to find some solution, but always get some errors:

```
# sample dataframe
d = {'price':['−$13.79', '−$ 13234.79', '$ 132834.79', 'R$ 75.900,00', 'R$ 69.375,12', '- $ 2344.92']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I tried this code, first wanted just to find solution.

```
df['price'] = (df.price.str.replace("−$", "-").str.replace(r'\w+\$\s+', '').str.replace('.', '')\
                   .str.replace(',', '').astype(float)) / 100
```

So idea was to convert -$ to - (for negative values). Then $ to ''.

But as a result I get:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '−$1379'

Comment: by default, `str.replace` interprets the passed argument as a regex and `$` has a special meaning here (end of string), so you need to escape it by `replace(r"−\$", "-")` or use `regex=False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the numbers on one side, and identify whether there is a minus in the other side, then combine:

```
factor = np.where(df['price'].str.match(r'[−-]'), -1, 1)/100
out = (pd.to_numeric(df['price'].str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')
         .mul(factor)
       )
```

output:

```
0       -13.79
1    -13234.79
2    132834.79
3     75900.00
4     69375.12
5     -2344.92
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you. Minus is not 'the minus',  data was parsed and as output got data with this type of minus, so i should replace it. However this code works. Thank you

Comment: you can put all the variations of minuses that you want in the regex ;)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `re` ?

Like this:

```
import re
df['price'] = float(re.sub(r'[^\-.0-9]', '', df.price.str)) / 100
```

I'm just removing by regex all the symbols that are not 0-9, ".", "," & "-".

BTW, no clue why you divide it by 100...

Answer (score 1):

```
df["price2"] = pd.to_numeric(df["price"].str.replace("[R$\s\.,]", "")) / 100
df["price3"] = df["price"].str.replace("[R$\s\.,]", "").astype(float) / 100
df
```

A few notes:

The dot is the regex symbel for everything.
The `-` symbel you are using is not a minus. Its something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
df["price2"] = pd.to_numeric(df["price"].str.replace("[R$\s\.,]", "")) / 100
df["price3"] = df["price"].str.replace("[R$\s\.,]", "").astype(float) / 100
df
```

A few notes:

The dot is the regex symbel for everything.
The `-` symbel you are using is not a minus. Its something else.
I would use something like https://regex101.com for debugging.